# TextLocal Java API template message error 80

Tags: java, textlocal

I am trying to send an sms through TextLocal API using Java but I get error 80: invalid template. I also tried to run the same url in a browser and I still get the same error. please tell me how I can fix this

```
{"errors":[{"code":80,"message":"Invalid template"}],"status":"failure"}

API Key: dasdasdasdasdasdasd
message: 2950 is the otp for app registration. Thanks - TECH SCFGGH PVT LTD

https://api.textlocal.in/send/?apikey=dasdasdasdasdasdasd&numbers=1234567899&message=2950%20is%20the%20otp%20for%20app%20registration.%20Thanks%20-%20TECH%20SCFGGH%20PVT%20LTD&sender=XTCTCF
```

Comment: key is not real, it is fake and I have not revealed any confidential information

Answer (score 0):

according to the official doc [here](https://api.textlocal.in/docs/sendsms)

you are sending a message that "given didn't match any approved templates on your account."

Comment: My template is like this:%%|OTP^{"inputtype" : "text", "maxlength" : "4"}%% is the otp for app registration. Thanks - TECH SCFGGH PVT LTD

Comment: The template is approved by TextLocal and also I am able to send to send SMS through their site using the same template

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from the TextLocal Support, there was a space after sender. So

```
XTCTCF%20 instead of XTCTCF
```